# Join with unknown table name

Tags: mysql, join

I need to join table1 and table2. I don't know the name of table2, but it is a record in table 1. so I'm trying this:

```
SELECT table2.*
from table1 t
JOIN ( 
    SELECT tname from table1 t1 WHERE t.id = t1.id
    ) as table2 ON table2.ref = t.ref
WHERE ...
```

but it is not working. Any ideas? thanks

my error is: "Unknown column 't.id' in 'where clause'"

Comment: `table2` _is_ the name of `table2` since you defined its alias with `AS table2`.

Comment: How does `tname` fit in ? Is that the name of a table, or some other value? It is unclear because it is not referenced in your `WHERE`.

Comment: A sample of rows from `table1` along with a sample of the query output you hope to produce would be helpful.

Comment: basically he doesnt know what tables he is joining with until table2 tells him based on the inner select statement condition...you cannot join in this way especially since you are missing your `ON` clause...also are you sure you want `t.*` and not `table2.*` because if so then the join is useless...also why didn't you decide to just use `t.tname` instead of the whole join on itself idea?

Comment: actually I have a `ON` condition. And yes, i want `table2.*`, i can edit that.

Comment: now do you want to join with the table whose name is the evaluation of `t1.tname` or do you want to join with the physical result of the SELECT statement (which is what you are doing)

Comment: I want to join with the table whose name is the evaluation of `t1.tname`

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your query to be like below. Give it a try

```
SELECT t.*
from table1 t
JOIN ( 
    SELECT id, tname from table1
    WHERE some_condition
    ) table2 on t.id = table2.id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Yes and then you can join with the outer result set. Though in our original query the condition in inner query `WHERE t.id = t1.id` doesn't make sense much but you can include any arbitrary where condition.

Comment: @CarloMazzabruttaCappai, consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.